# Why can't I see different financial types in contribution reports

Tags: custom-fields, contributions, price-sets, financial-types, percentage-price-field

With our contributions, one payment may contain 3 financial types ... e.g. an event fee, membership fee and donation. I have created "Price Sets" (of one Financial Type), which then contain 3 different "Price Fields" (which have separate Financial Types allocated) but when it comes to reporting on Contribution Detail, the filter / field "Financial Type" only pulls through "Event fees".

I can see that when creating an event I can choose 1 financial type
When creating a Price Set I can choose 1 financial type
But I can add multiple Price Fields to a Price Set, but these aren't being detailed / broken down when I go to the reporting on Financial Type.

Help! Are we setting up the price sets incorrectly? Do we need to create Custom Fields?

++ Added info: when running an Event Participant Report, if you select Fee Level as a column it groups all the different "Option Labels" from the various Price Fields within the Price Set. So the information is there and separated, I just can't see how the associated values for teach of those option labels listed for each participant.

Thanks so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for some advanced reporting: install this extension: fuzion extended reports -> and then look for report template: Extended Report - Price Set Line Items.

Comment: I am quite keen to find a coalition of the willing to help us tackle building an option in Find Contributions to flip over to searching by Line Item. it seems to catch a lot of folk

Comment: Yeah - Fuzion's Extended Report is my goto now - should be shipped w/ Core; it's also really easy to extend (add on extra columns) Extended Reports; Merci Fuzion!